# Input fields and other objects display fading boxes around such elements only in CCleaner Browser A.K.A. Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome

I've got an issue going on with my CCleaner internet web browser (which is built on Chrome). These silver-white borders appear over elements on web pages, and even the whole page itself, whenever I click on such an element. It only happens inside the CCleaner browser window, not in "regular" Chrome.

Here I would like to provide an example, taken from my edit account settings here on Stack Overflow dot com (a page you can look at that is exactly the same as mine except for my issue with my web browser).

[image: Click Here to View Image]

OK so in that pic the border you see around the text entry box is what I get all the time. The box is not permanent; it slowly fades out and dissolves.

How do I prevent these silver borders from appearing in the first place?

Comment: I see that people are looking at my post, but no one so far has commented. Have I left something out? Is something I posted wrong? Please let me know so I can fix it, if it needs fixing.

Comment: This question is off-topic here since it is not about programming. You should ask on https://superuser.com/ instead. Check out their help page: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic. But most of all, be sure to ask a question. You haven't actually asked one here.

Comment: How do I prevent these silver borders from appearing in the first place?

That's my question, right up there. ^|^

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.